# Crawling complex structure

Tags: javascript, automation

I'm trying to recursively crawl a pretty complex structure and parse the DOM content of it, for example -

**Base URI:** https://website.com/page/

Links to crawl: https://website.com/page/1, https://website.com/page/2

**Base URI:** https://website.com/page/1

Links to crawl: https://website.com/page/1/angular.html

Where angular.html will be the page with content loaded after DOM has been parsed.

I have the following JS code, but I have no idea how to keep crawling and printing the DOM's content recursively

```
var listOfLinks = [];
var collectLinks = document.links;
for(var i=0; i<collectLinks.length; i++) 
{
  listOfLinks.push(collectLinks[i].href);
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Your code has nothing that crawls: you need at least to launch a request...

Comment: @trincot I'm running it from Devtools on the page I need.

Comment: *"on the page I need"*: then I don't understand your question. You are listing multiple links, so are you saying you don't need those other pages? If you do need them, you need to request them.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, I'm just trying to recursively crawl pages from the same base URI and get the content of them.

Comment: You need to write a recursive function. Keep calling the function from inside itself as long as there are documents/links to download.

Comment: @slebetman Thanks, and how can I fetch the content of the page after it was loaded to the DOM?

Comment: Maybe first concentrate on fetching the content of **one** page given a URL. I see no code in your question that does that.